# How to handle non transient exception in Azure Worker role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus, azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

We have two azure worker roles - A and B.

- A is a Quartz scheduler which runs jobs every minute.
- It reads some ids from a 'Redis cache' every minutes and execute jobs for those ids.
- 'A' publish its output to a service bus queue which is
  subscribed by Worker role 'B'.
- 'B' worker role reads values from
  queue and execute some more operation on them.
- Both worker roles has
  to build cache on startup.

Now here are few issues regarding Azure component failure:

- If Redis cache goes down, how can we handle that. We need to stop our execution till the time it is up again and then we need to build our cache again. 'B' worker role should stop pulling message from service bus till the time Redis comes up again.
- How to handle Service bus failure in worker role 'B'?

Comment: Should you implement a circuit breaker ? Otherwise you can configure service bus with a custom transient fault detection, Are you using c# ?

Comment: We can check circuit breaker. But configuring service bus would not help as we are concerned about non-transient errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stop any of the worker roles.

**Worker role A should be resilient to issues in Redis cache**, meaning that your code should handle any exception thrown by Redis (or network exceptions), either by retry or swallow the exception.

**Worker role B should constantly pull messages from the service bus**. If worker role A doesn't publish data, then worker role B should handle empty results.

**Stopping your service on Redis/Azure glitch will require you to handle more complicated scenarios** - for example: automatically detect if Redis is up again and automatically start your service.

Comment: We have implemented retry for transient exceptions but in case we face any non-transient exceptions, we don't want to continue as we know that we cannot process message until cache comes again. Apart from that we need to make sure that cache data is built again (when cache service is up again) before start processing messages again.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution would be to configure an external health service that your workers check before pulling from the service bus or cache. If the health service says the cache or service bus are down your workers simply don't attempt to process anything.

Comment: Checking external service before each operation can introduce unacceptable latency.

Comment: @Pragmatic sure. Plenty of ways to prevent that too.